# Simple openGL code paradox

Tags: opengl

I'm trying to create the most basic application that will draw a cube using indices and textures for starters, but nothing about it makes any sense whatsoever.

I ran it on my machine with an nVidia card and the display driver (latest, not that it matters) crashes (null ref), along with the program on the `glDrawElements(...)` command (`Renderer.cpp`). Fine. Then I sent it to a friend of mine who has an AMD card to try to debug it because I was unable to find the bug in the code, and the program worked (didn't crash) on his machine.

That surprised me since I only did the most basic openGL stuff, no way it was vendor specific. To get to the bottom of this, I downloaded APItrace (http://apitrace.github.io/) to try to see what's going on under the hood of my machine and why does my driver crash.

Once I dumped the trace after I ran the program, it said that the shader program linker failed because I didn't write to gl_Position (which I have).

The problem is that the program links just fine in VS debugger and no error is returned there. So it just keeps getting weirder.

If you want to mess with this, you can get the code (commit with issue linked) at https://github.com/Karlovsky120/7DaysWorldEditor/commit/e86b8be40c81511c4416dc5e253b90e42a5a8ec0

I don't think you'd see the bug if I just pasted the code here, there must be a mistake with the setup somewhere.

I really made an effort to make this as hassle free as possible, it's just one click install: clone it, build it, and you're good to go, no additional setup required. You will need to open it with VS2017 though.

There's a lot of classes in the code, but all of the relevant code is in `Scene.cpp` and any of the classes it references.

Thank you for any help you give, even if it's just a guess at what might be wrong because I'm at my wits end here.

Comment: Are your drivers up to date? Do they support OpenGL 4.0? Could OpenGL be using an on board graphics card instead of the dedicated one?

Comment: I have the 10 series card with the latest driver, and since the nvidia dll is the one to crash (and the vendor in openGL state is nVidia) I'm pretty sure the dedicated card is the one used.

Comment: "The most basic application that will draw a cube" really does not require 78 source files and 43,000 lines of code.  Was going to take a quick look but geez you're not making it easy for people to help.

Comment: How did it work on your friends machine? In Renderer::render, I don't see any of your 3 buffers being bound and no calls to vertexattribpointer. Nor do I see a uniform for your texture. I wouldn't expect glDrawElements to do anything. Did you copy this code? Did your friend run the original version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right before the draw call, there is a single line of code missing.
I failed to bind the index buffer, which resulted in null ref on the card.

The line in question is:
`glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1);`

It should go right before the draw call.

Answer (score 2):

Loader.cpp, line 112:

```
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 3 * indexCount, indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

Whatever else is going on, that is wrong. You are telling opengl to copy triple the data that is actually available to the index buffer, meaning the final two thirds of it is garbage. I can't categorically say if this is causing the issue, but it's a good place to start.

I've encountered issues before where some errors are treated less strictly by one vendor (It was a while ago so I can't remember which vendor), so that might explain why it doesn't crash on an AMD card.

Honestly this code looks like much of it has been copy/pasted. If I were you, I'd go over all your OpenGL code and double check it.

Comment: You were right, bu it unfortunately didn't fix the problem. I'll keep poking around  to see whats happening. Ah, the code is thrown together, I want to have the basic thing working and then I'll move it around and make it nice.

Comment: I was missing `glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, 1);` before the draw call. Sigh.

Comment: Glad to hear you fixed it. Please put that information in an answer to your question, and mark it as accepted when you can.